# App service not being fount by nginx service after restart on aws ecs fargate with service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-route53, aws-fargate, service-discovery

I have two services on my cluster: myapp-service and an nginx-service. I'm using service discovery to connect the both and everything works just fine.

The problem happens when i deploy a new version of myapp-service and it came with a new private(and public) ip address. After the deploy i see that the ip are correctly updated on the Route 53 but when i try to access my-app through nginx it return a bad-gateway. When i look to the nginx logs on Cloudwatch i can see that the nginx are trying to connect to the old private ip address of myapp-service.

- currently i'm not using any loadbalance or auto-scaling configuration.
- There are any health check for my containers on the task definition.
- "Enable ECS task health propagation" is on.

This is my nginx configuration(default.conf) and marketplace-service.local is my registry on Route 53.

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server marketplace-service.local:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
    }

}
```

Can anybody help me to discover what i'm missing here??

thx

Comment: Hi, have you manage to solve this issue? If yes, please add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `upstream` part.

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server marketplace-service.local:8000;
}
```

But I'm sure about `server` part. For `Fargate`, `localhost` is used so add `server_name localhost;`. Then add 4 lines of code showing below to `location` block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to DNS caching. Nginx, like many servers caches DNS lookups, which means that Nginx doesnt perform a DNS lookup for each request it proxies. instead, it resolves the DNS name once and reuses that IP address for a certain period (defined by the DNS entry's Time To Live (TTL)).

The tricky part in your case is coming from the proxy_pass directive which make Nginx to resolves the address defined in the proxy_pass just once — on startup and do not honor the route53 record TTL !

When you update channels-backend service it gets a new IP address, The Nginx service continues to use the old IP address until you restart Nginx. This is why you see Nginx trying to connect to the old IP address and returning a bad gateway error.

In order to be able to solve this problem permanently, you have to explicitly tell Nginx to respect the TTL using the resolver and valid directives, in conjuction with the use of a variable in the proxy_pass directive.

```
resolver <DNS_IP_ADDRESS> valid=10s;

upstream channels-backend {
    server marketplace-service.local:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        set $backend "http://channels-backend";
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }
}
```

Replace <DNS_IP_ADDRESS> according to your DNS server IP.
Possible DNS addresses:

1. 169.254.169.253 ( if you are using awsvpc as your network mode )
2. Base VPC cidr your ecs services resides plus 2 (for example: if your VPC cidr is 10.0.0.0/16 , than use 10.0.0.2 as the DNS server IP .)
3. 127.0.0.11 ( default DNS server for Docker containers )

**I'm not sure about the third option but I think it should work.**

If your location block manipulates the URI (eg. rewrite), consider using map instead of set. I had a similar problem and map is the only solution that worked for me.

```
# When specifying multiple servers, they are queried in the order
# they appear in the directive

resolver 10.0.0.2 169.254.169.253 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;

upstream channels-backend {
    server marketplace-service.local:8000;
}

map $request_uri $backend {
    hostnames;
    default http://channels-backend;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location ~ ^/api/ {
        rewrite  ^/api/(.*) /$1 break; 
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }
}
```